# Date Operation Filter in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I am working on a Dataset where I need to keep the date column in format 2023-01-01 but PowerBI by default has format 1/1/2023
Later I need to filter rows where date is greater than 2023/01/01

I am using following MQuery to perform the desired operation but getting issues

```
#"ChangeDateFormat" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Source", {{"Datecolumn", each Date.ToText(_,"yyyy-MM-dd"), type date}}),
#"Result"=Table.SelectRows(#"ChangeDateFormat", each [Datecolumn] >= #Date(2023,01,01)
```

Currently this is giving me error saying that this cannot be operated. Can someone let me know what I am doing wrong and how can this be corrected.

Comment: Did any of these answers solve your question? If so please toggle the checkmark to mark that answer as solving your issue, and use arrows to upvote it

Answer (score 0):

See [documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/set-a-locale-or-region-for-data-power-query-d42b9390-1fff-413f-8120-d7df0ced20b9) on setting region format for a specific column, like a date column which reads:

"In addition to the default Locale setting of a workbook, you can specify a non-default locale setting to use when you apply a specific Change Type operation over one or more columns. This is helpful when importing data with different regional settings across multiple queries, yet you want a specific default setting to be consistent for all queries in the workbook.

With the Change Type operation, you can specify the destination data type as well as the locale setting to use for the conversion.

1. To open a query, locate one previously loaded from the Power Query Editor, select a cell in the data, and then select Query > Edit. For more information see Create, load, or edit a query in Excel.
2. Right click a column header, and then select Change Type > Using Locale.
3. In the Change Type with Locale dialog box, select a data type and locale.
4. Select OK.

Answer (score 0):

In PowerQuery, you can't change the date format and you don't need to. So long as it is of Date data type then you are good. So no need for your `#"ChangeDateFormat"` step.

Instead, you set the date format in the model, after the data has loaded.
[image]